# How to configure project is compiled for es6 notation

Tags: typescript, npm, es6-promise

I develop the project on Angular 2 + PrimeNG. Begin to use Git, the problem surfaced in the compilation of the TypeScript. At once will fragment your package.json.

```
"dependencies": {
 "@angular/common": "2.4.2",
 "@angular/compiler": "2.4.2",
 "@angular/core": "2.4.2",
 "@angular/forms": "2.4.2",
 "@angular/http": "2.4.2",
 "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.2",
 "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.2",
 "@angular/router": "3.4.2",
 "ag-grid": "12.0.0",
 "ag-grid-angular": "12.0.0",
 "angular2-focus": "^1.1.0",
 "core-js": "^2.4.1",
 "font-awesome": "^4.6.3",
 "moment": "^2.18.1",
"primeng": "^2.0.0",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
"rxjs": "5.0.1",
"tedious": "1.14.0",
"zone.js": "^0.7.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
 "@angularclass/hmr": "^1.0.1",
 "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "^3.0.2",
 "@types/core-js": "^0.9.0",
 "@types/jasmine": "2.5.41",
 "@types/lodash": "4.14.50",
 "@types/node": "^6.0.38",
 "@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.53.33",
 "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
 "autoprefixer": "^6.3.2",
 "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.17",
 "codelyzer": "2.0.0-beta.4",
 "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
 "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
 "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
 "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
 "html-loader": "^0.4.0",
 "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.8.1",
 "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^0.2.0",
 "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
 "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^2.4.0",
 "json-loader": "^0.5.3",
 "karma": "1.3.0",
 "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
 "karma-coverage": "^1.0.0",
 "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
 "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.3",
 "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.2.1",
 "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
 "karma-webpack": "1.8.0",
 "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
 "null-loader": "0.1.1",
 "postcss-loader": "^1.1.0",
 "protractor": "^4.0.10",
 "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
 "remap-istanbul": "^0.6.4",
 "rimraf": "^2.5.1",
 "sass-loader": "^4.0.0",
 "shelljs": "^0.7.0",
 "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
 "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
 "tslint": "^4.3.1",
 "tslint-loader": "^3.3.0",
 "typedoc": "^0.5.1",
 "typescript": "2.0.10",
 "url-loader": "^0.5.6",
 "webpack": "2.1.0-beta.25",
 "webpack-dev-server": "2.1.0-beta.9"
}
}
```

After cloning repo from project installing all npm packages, build the project, obtain a set of errors of this kind (here is a fragment of the compile log).

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@angular/router/src/utils  /collection.d.ts:35:58
TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:47:36
TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterable'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:353:48
TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
```

The situation is known - don't see the types of es5. The file tsconfig.json like this:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"target": "es5",
"module": "commonjs",
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"sourceMap": true,
"noEmitHelpers": true,
"noUnusedLocals": true,
"noUnusedParameters": true
},
"compileOnSave": false,
"buildOnSave": false,
"awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
  "forkChecker": true,
  "useWebpackText": true
 }
}
```

Began to translate the compiler TS in es6 mode to resolve the problem, "target": "es6". The error log was:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/handlebars/index.d.ts:22:77
TS2314: Generic type 'HandlebarsTemplateDelegate<T, any>' requires 2 type   argument(s).

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/handlebars/index.d.ts:24:34
TS2368: Type parameter name cannot be 'any'

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/handlebars/index.d.ts:24:79
TS2314: Generic type 'HandlebarsTemplateDelegate<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/handlebars/index.d.ts:96:15
TS2314: Generic type 'HandlebarsTemplateDelegate<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/handlebars/index.d.ts:99:42
TS2368: Type parameter name cannot be 'any'

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/handlebars/index.d.ts:104:22
TS2314: Generic type 'HandlebarsTemplateDelegate<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/handlebars/index.d.ts:115:34
TS2314: Generic type 'HandlebarsTemplateDelegate<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
```

I have the feeling that the project is not aware of the types of es6 in principle. How to correctly configure the compilation project under the es6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use "es5" as TypeScript compiler "target" for an angular project currently, [it's a baseline requirement, es6 is not wildly supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34288787/es6-as-the-typescript-target-compiler-option-for-angularjs-or-angular2).

But features like "Promise" & "DOM.Iterable" are not supported in ES5, so you have to add additional compilation options for loading these libraries. The solution is add `"lib": ["es2015", "dom"]` into your "tsconfig.json":

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"target": "es5",
"lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
"module": "commonjs",
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"sourceMap": true,
"noEmitHelpers": true,
"noUnusedLocals": true,
"noUnusedParameters": true
},
"compileOnSave": false,
"buildOnSave": false,
"awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
  "forkChecker": true,
  "useWebpackText": true
 }
}
```

This option is mentioned at "[Angular 2 guide - TypeScript Configuration](https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration)"

> Based on the --target, TypeScript adds additional ambient declarations
>   like Promise if the target is es6.
>
> Since the QuickStart is targeting es5, you can override the list of
>   declaration files to be included:
>
> > "lib": ["es2015", "dom"]
>
> Thanks to that, you have all the es6 typings even when targeting es5.