# How can I compile Angular libraries to ES2016?

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I'm making the decision to no longer support legacy browsers AT ALL and dropping support for ES5 compilation/polyfills.

I have my Angular project code compiling for ~85% coverage to

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
        "es2019",
        "dom"
```

These options control the project's code.

However, Angular libraries compile to ES2015.

How can we compile our project's VENDOR packages to ES2016/17/18/19/20?

UPDATE: Answered in [stackoverflow.com/a/68294105/1440240](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68294105/1440240)

Comment: If you're going to use ES2020 module syntax, why not target ES2020? Not enough was added in ES2016 (`Array.prototype.includes` and exponent syntax) to warrant going through the trouble (IMO). ES2020 gets you optional chaining and nullish coalescing.

Comment: Well it looks like pretty bad coverage though https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/ es2016 is looking pretty safe. Either way, how would you do it?

Comment: The link you sent was for "ESNext" which are proposals which are generally not implemented (except for Stage 3 proposals). You want to look at [2016+ which is where ES2020 is](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/). It has broad support, except for obsolete browsers like IE11 and Edge (Chakra), and ESR versions of Firefox. Personally, I try to keep my ES versions the same across `target`, `module` and `lib`. Which version I choose depends on the client I'm working for and what their tolerance for risk is.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @Dennis no but actually the word is that Angular team is working on something similar but there is currently no way to do this for the Angular vendor files. All we seem to be able to do is use differential loading to load polyfills for old browsers only. I think we're stuck until the team gives us a solution. Perhaps with Webpack 5 updates.

Answer (score 1):

According to this stackoverflow post [ES6 as the typescript target compiler option for angularjs or angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34288787/es6-as-the-typescript-target-compiler-option-for-angularjs-or-angular2)

it seems like `"target": "es6"` will do your task.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, that only applies to your project code. I'll update my question with the link to the docs.